# Why is the isotope Lithium 6 stable against alpha decay?

Tags: energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, radiation, binding-energy

According to the table the binding energy of *Helium 4* is 7.073915MeV/Nucleon while the binding of *Lithium 6* is 5.606291MeV/Nucleon. So why is the lithium 6 isotope not an alpha particle emitter?

I have considered the following decay reaction: $${}^6\text{Li}\to{}^4 \text{He} +{}^2\text{H}.$$ Charge, parity and spin are conserved. I don't see why this does not happen naturally?

Comment: And what is the total binding energy of each side of your equation? Note that the atomic mass of 6Li is less than that of 4He+2H...

Comment: @RealKiller69 I've typeset your reaction equations, see <https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation> for information how to typeset equations here. I've also slightly edited the wording – feel free to undo what you don't like.

Comment: Further to @SebastianRiese's comment, if you ever ask a question on chemistry.se, you can use `\ce` instead of `\text`.

Comment: @J.G. That works here too, with [one extra step](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13118/44126).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the loosely-bound deuteron.

The binding energy per nucleon ($BE/A = \rm1.1\,MeV$ for $\rm^2H$) isn't the right thing to look at, because you have to un-weight by the number of nucleons.  Plus when you start looking at beta decays, binding energy per nucleon makes it hard to account for the neutron-proton mass difference.  As a commenter says, you have to look at the *masses* of the initial and final states.  I personally prefer to look a the [mass excesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_excess), which in this case are

| nuclide | $\Delta$ |
| --- | --- |
| $\rm^2H$ | 13.1 MeV |
| $\rm^4He$ | 2.4 MeV |
| $\rm^6Li$ | 14.1 MeV |

Because $13.1 + 2.4 > 14.1$, your final state is heavier than your initial state, and the decay is forbidden.